# How do I solve this error "An argument of 'series float' type was used but a 'input float' is expected" in Pine Script Version 5

Tags: error-handling, compiler-errors, pine-script, pine-script-v5, indicator

I'm writing a Pine Script Indicator and I'm getting 4 errors and one warning after compiling:

1. Cannot call 'hline' with argument 'price'='upperBound'. An argument of 'series float' type was used but a 'input float' is expected
2. Cannot call 'hline' with argument 'price'='lowerBound'. An argument of 'series float' type was used but a 'input float' is expected
3. Cannot call 'fill' with argument 'hline1'='upperBound'. An argument of 'series float' type was used but a 'hline' is expected
4. Cannot call 'fill' with argument 'hline2'='lowerBound'. An argument of 'series float' type was used but a 'hline' is expected

(1) warning: The `transp` argument is deprecated. We recommend using color.new() or color.rgb() functions to specify the transparency of the plots instead. Additionally, note that `transp` has no effect in plots where the color is calculated at runtime

This is my Pine Script Code:

```
'''
//@version=5

// Define the number of bars to be analyzed for finding clusters
clusterLength = input(title="Cluster Length", defval=100)

// Define the number of standard deviations from the mean to determine the cluster
stdDev = input(title="Number of Standard Deviations", defval=2.0)

// Calculate the mean and standard deviation for the defined number of bars
mean = ta.sma(close, clusterLength)
stddev = ta.stdev(close, clusterLength)

// Plot the upper and lower bounds of the clusters as horizontal lines
upperBound = mean + stddev * stdDev
lowerBound = mean - stddev * stdDev
hline(upperBound, color=color.red, linewidth=2, title="Upper Bound")
hline(lowerBound, color=color.blue, linewidth=2, title="Lower Bound")

// Fill the area between the bounds to visually represent the cluster
fill(upperBound, lowerBound, color=color.gray, transp=70)
'''
```

I would appreciate if you provide a solution.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use dynamic values in `hline()`.

You can try using `plot()` or `line` instead.

And you should be calling the `fill()` function with `plot`s or `hline`s. `upperBound` and `lowerBound` are just variables.

See the signature below:

```
fill(hline1, hline2, color, title, editable, fillgaps, display) → void
fill(plot1, plot2, color, title, editable, show_last, fillgaps, display) → void
```